# Search command don't work in conjunction with overflow menu in Codenameone

Tags: command, toolbar, codenameone, overflow-menu

The action from Search Command doesn't work, but the action from Overflow Menu still work.

This is my code

```
getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> {
        String text = (String) e.getSource();
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            this.undoSearch(this);
        } else {
            this.fetchComponents(this, text);
        }
        getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }, 4);
```

```
getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu("Enviar", null, (ActionListener) (e) -> {
        Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(() -> {
            boolean success = this.appView.getService().updateTicket(ticket);
            if (success) {
                this.appView.showSuccess("Enviado com sucesso!");
            } else {
                this.appView.showError(new Exception("Ocorreu algum erro ao enviar!"));
            }
        });
    });
```

I just want to do samething like it:

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Notice that when you click the search button the title is replaced with a text field where you should type your query, does that happen?

Comment: No, it does not happen when I add the Search Command and, later, the OverflowMenu

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this and it worked as expected:

```
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

Form f = new Form("AAAA", BoxLayout.y()); 

f.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> Log.p("Searching: " + e.getSource()));
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToOverflowMenu("Hi", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, e -> Log.p("Overflow"));

f.show();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works only when i remove the code "  this.animateLayout(100);" from my class

Comment: What's "this"? If it's the form then yes it might collide with the animation to install the search bar.